# Using a global flag for python RegExp compile

Tags: python, regex

Would it be possible to define a global flag so that Python's `re.compile()` automatically sets it ? For instance I want to use `re.DOTALL` flag for all my RegExp in -- say -- a class?

It may sound weird at first, but I'm not really in control of this part of the code since it's generated by YAPPS. I just give YAPPS a string containing a RegExp and it calls `re.compile()`. Alas, I need to use it in `re.DOTALL` mode.

A quick fix would be to edit the generated parser and add the proper option. But I still hope there's another and more automated way to do this.

EDIT:
Python allows you to set flags with the (?...) construct, so in my case re.DOTALL is (?s). Though usefull, it doesn't apply on a whole class, or on a file.

So my question still holds.

Comment: Wooble answered the same thing, earlier and took time to write down an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can change it to be globally `re.DOTALL`. But you *shouldn't*. Global settings are a bad idea at the best of times -- this could cause any Python code run by the same instance of Python to break.

---

So, **don't do this**:

The way you can change it is to use the fact that the Python interpreter caches modules per instance, so that if somebody else imports the same module they get the object to which you also have access. So you could rebind `re.compile` to a proxy function that passes `re.DOTALL`.

```
import re
re.my_compile = re.compile
re.compile = lambda pattern, flags: re.my_compile(pattern, flags | re.DOTALL)
```

and this change will happen to everybody else.

You can even package this up in a context manager, as follows:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def flag_regexen(flag):
    import re
    re.my_compile = re.compile
    re.compile = lambda pattern, flags: re.my_compile(pattern, flags | flag)
    yield
    re.compile = re.my_compile
```

and then

```
with flag_regexen(re.DOTALL):
    <do stuff with all regexes DOTALLed>
```

Comment: Well, if it's for a class only, it might be usefull. You just answered my question.

Comment: @EEva: yes, but even though it's only applying to the class, while the flag hack is active __all__ Python being run -- functions in other modules, anything you import, anything that calls -- will have their regexes DOTALLed. This may not cause a problem now, or ever, but if it does the problem will be nasty and difficult to catch.

Comment: @EEva: it's like, I don't know, making `sys.version` return a tuple in a different order. It's unlikely that you'll ever cause a problem, but because the output is not meant to be changed by 3rd-party code, it will cause bugs in places that shouldn't have bugs.

Answer (score 8):

All of the flags can be set in the regular expression itself:

```
r"(?s)Your.*regex.*here"
```

Comment: Yup, it's in the documentation. Sorry about that, I missed it.

Comment: Still, I'd like to know if there's a more global way, like importing something or redefining something...